# Smart Objects Problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I have a file with a layer that has a smart object. I want to copy the whole layer and relink the smart object to another file. When I copy the whole group as a new layer, I somehow can't unlink the layer/

Comment: You can't "relink a smart object to another file" So I'm not really sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on the smart object layer and select "new smart object via copy" and this will give you a new separate independent smart object layer, which you can then copy over to the other file. Not sure if this solves you're issue.